# Should I be using Inner Classes? Example Code inside

Tags: java, inner-classes

I like consolidating my code/`classes` as much as possible without each `class` itself getting messy.  So I looked into using `NestedClasses`, though `InnerClasses` in this case because the `InnerClass` needs access the `OuterClass`'s members.

---

## Example

Lets say I have a program that calculates various shape attributes to shapes.  So given a Rectangle Shape, it would find the Area/Perimeter from inputs of length and width.

I would first create an `abstract class Shape`, which has `abstract methods` `getArea()` and `getPerimeter()`.  I would then create my `subclass` `RectangleShape`, `extend` the shape `class`, `@Override` those  `methods` with the necessary logic.

Now there's a shape Rectangular Prism (Cube).  It has the same `variables`/`methods` as `RectangleShape` does, but with one extra, height.  In the past I would create another `subclass` of `RectangleShape` and go from there.

Is it better/not worse to use an `InnerClass` instead and have an `abstract class` `PrismShape`? I ask this because `Prisms` share the same methods, no matter the shape. If you're at all confused by the above I'm posting code below of what I'm saying.

---

### Example Code

#### `Shape Class`

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public abstract double getArea();
    public abstract double getPerimeter();
}
```

---

#### `PrismShape Class`

```
public abstract class PrismShape{        
    public abstract double getVolume();
    public abstract double getSurfaceArea();
    public abstract double getLateralArea();
    
}
```

---

#### `RectangleShape Class`

```
import Abstract.Shape;
import Abstract.ShapePrism;

public class RectangleShape extends Shape{
    //Variables Declared
    private double _length, _width;

    //Constructor
    public RectangleShape(double _length, double _width) {
        setLength(_length);
        setWidth(_width);
    }

    //Getters and Setters
    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return getLength() * getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return (2 * getLength())+ (2 * getWidth());
    }
        
    public double getLength() {
        return _length;
    }

    private void setLength(double _length) {
        this._length = _length;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return _width;
    }

    private void setWidth(double _width) {
        this._width = _width;
    }
    
    //Inner Class Prism
    public class RecPrismShape extends PrismShape{
        
        //Variables Declared
        private double _height;
        
        //Constructor
        public RecPrismShape(double _height) {
            setHeight(_height);
        }        
     
        //Getters and Setters
        @Override
        public double getSurfaceArea(){
            return (getLateralArea() + (2 * getArea()));
        }
    
        @Override
        public double getVolume(){
            return getArea() * getHeight();
        }
    
        @Override
        public double getLateralArea(){
            return getPerimeter() * getHeight();
        }

        public double getHeight() {
            return _height;
        }

        private void setHeight(double _height) {
            this._height = _height;
        }        
    }
    
}
```

---

I'm open to criticism, still fairly new to Java.  My thought process during this was I have 2d Shape attributes and 3d (Prism) shape attributes.  The 3d Shapes derive their attributes from 2d shapes, but not visa versa.  So for me at least having `InnerClasses` makes sense.

Comment: This example is poorly contrived because your example base classes do not contain implementation, and thus could just be `Interfaces`s which any class can implement as many as you want. Typically, inner classes in most languages (but especially in `Java`) are only used when you are declaring that the ``InnerClass`` is only ever used in the context of the ``OuterClass``.

Comment: @aruisdante Assuming I'm using Abstract in this case, and the implementation is calculating the shape attributes given user input, does that help?  I'm trying to keep it as concise as possible, long questions aren't fun, though I suppose this one was long.  As well as I'm not changing the Top level classes ever, it's set framework.

Comment: Ok, but in that case, is there a reason that ``ShapePrism`` doesn't extend ``Shape``? If the point is to create a distinct set of 2D shapes and 3D shapes, they're really separate class trees and I still don't really see why you should try and relate them via an ``InnerClass``.

Comment: @aruisdante I suppose that could be a better implementation (`ShapePrism` extending `Shape`).  Now that I think about it why am forcing myself to create the Rectangle Object when I'm trying to find the Prism attributes?  Frees space up.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: No problem. Another thing to think about is that, in this case a 2D-shape is really just a special case of a 3D shape with ``height = 0``, and whose 3D methods would return 0.

Comment: It's a question of design pattern more than a correct approach. I suggest you read the [nested classes tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) along with [when to use them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html).

Comment: Please do not use underscores when naming non-constant variables. There are naming conventions in Java and you would do well to adhere to them.

Answer (score 1):

My own take on this: A public inner class seems most useful when the rest of the program has an object of the outer class, and it wants to create an object of the inner class that "belongs" to the outer class object in some way; that is, it's tightly associated with it.

The way you've arranged things, however, it means that if the client wants to create a `RecPrismShape` object, it has to first create a `RectangleShape` object that the prism object will belong to.  Most likely, this is not going to be useful.  That is, the client creates a `RectangleShape rect` just because it has to, in order to create a `RecPrismShape`, and the `rect` object wouldn't be useful to it in any other way.

I think a better idea would be to have a `RecPrismShape` object have a `private RectangleShape` object as one of its fields, but this would be an "implementation detail".  That way, you'd get to reuse the `RectangleShape` code, which it seems like you're trying to do.

```
public class RecPrismShape extends RectangleShape {

    private RectangleShape rect;
    private double height;

    public RecPrismShape(double length, double width, double height) {
        rect = new RectangleShape(length, width);
        this.height = height;
    }

    // and just one example of how you could use it
    public double getVolume() {
        return rect.getArea() * getHeight();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, I agree with you.  I'm going to go another direction however, as someone suggested above, and having a single Prism class for each shape and for the 2d objects have a height of 0.